# How to convert timestamp to time in java?

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

How can I convert MySQL timestamp to time in java? I tried something with SimpleDateFormat but it didn't work.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Show what you tried. Explain what errors you got. Also, do a search; questions about how to parse or format dates are one of the most frequently asked questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Show us what you tried...post some code.

Comment: How are you reading it from the `ResultSet`?  What error do you get?  Where is the code that doesn't work?

Comment: The answer written below helped me. It doesn't matter now! But thanks anyways...

Answer (score 0):

```
public Date getDate(Timestamp timestamp){
    return new Date(timestamp.getTime());
}
```